# Why isn't this script initiating?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to install a social sharebar jquery script. For some reason though, it's not loading up and I can't seem to find the cause of this.

In the head of the site, I have jquery loaded along with the jquery script like it states to do so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.moviepostersdb.com/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.moviepostersdb.com/js/jquery.social.share.2.2.js"></script>
```

The script installation also asks to put some extra scripting into the head:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function($){
$('#social-share').dcSocialShare();
size: 'horizontal',
    location: 'bottom',
    offsetAlign: 0,
    offsetLocation: 0,
    buttons: 'twitter,facebook,linkedin,digg,stumbleupon,delicious,pinterest,xing,buffer,print,email',
    floater: false,
    autoClose: true
});
});
</script>
```

That's also be implemented.

Before the body closing tag, the installation also asks to implement the following code... again, I've also done this:

```
<div id="social-share"></div>
```

Despite this, for some reason... the social sidebar isn't showing up on the site. Can anyone see what may be wrong?

www.moviepostersdb.com <--- URL of website.

Comment: Seems like you have just copied random parts of javascript and expect it to magically work. It doesn't happen in severe reality.

Comment: @zerkms: No; he's using a jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have a syntax error.

```
$('#social-share').dcSocialShare();
                                 ^-- closed here
```

I think you meant:

```
$(function(){
    $('#social-share').dcSocialShare({
        size: 'horizontal',
        location: 'bottom',
        offsetAlign: 0,
        offsetLocation: 0,
        buttons: 'twitter,facebook,linkedin,digg,stumbleupon,delicious,pinterest,xing,buffer,print,email',
        floater: false,
        autoClose: true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be:

```
$(function(){
 $('#social-share').dcSocialShare({
    size: 'horizontal',
    location: 'bottom',
    offsetAlign: 0,
    offsetLocation: 0,
    buttons: 'twitter,facebook,linkedin,digg,stumbleupon,delicious,pinterest,xing,buffer,print,email',
    floater: false,
    autoClose: true
 });
});
```

so `$('#social-share').dcSocialShare();` was a wrong close